# How can I show winmanager automatically?

Tags: vim

I’ve installed the winmanager, NERDTree and BufExplorer plugins. Now, I have `<F8>` set to toggle the winmanager display, using the following code in my `.vimrc`:

```
" mapping for triggering winmanager plugin
nnoremap <silent> <F8> :if IsWinManagerVisible() <BAR>WMToggle<CR><BAR> else<BAR> WMToggle<CR>:q<CR> endif <CR><CR>
```

This works fine.

What I want to do is to have winmanager show up automatically if the filetype is `.c` or `.cpp`. I added this to my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType c,cpp nested "\<F8>"
```

but it does *not* work.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you replace the `"\<F8>"` in your autocommand with the actual code you run in the mapping, does it work?

Comment: change to this: autocmd FileType c,cpp nested :if IsWinManagerVisible() <BAR>WMToggle<CR><BAR> else<BAR> WMToggle<CR>:q<CR> endif <CR><CR>  is does not work. i don't know the syntax, error info pops up. could you please give a help? meanwhile, i still don't like to repeat it.

Comment: from the vim help file, ":autocomd arguments are not expanded when the autocommand is defined". given this, what could i do to meet what i want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<F8>` is a normal-mode mapping, but `:autocmd` expects an Ex command on its right-hand side. You need to use `:normal` (without a `!` here, to allow mappings to take effect), and `:execute` to interpret the special key code:

```
:autocmd FileType c,cpp nested execute "normal \<F8>"
```

But I think it is cleaner to avoid the additional redirection and duplicate the mapping's commands instead:

```
:autocmd FileType c,cpp nested if IsWinManagerVisible() |exe 'WMToggle'| else| exe 'WMToggle' | quit | endif
```